# Binary Number Pattern in Python

Tags: python-3.x, printing

Print the following Pattern for the given number of Rows

**BINARY PATTERN**

Pattern for N = 4

1111

000

11

0

Pattern for N = 5

11111

0000

111

00

1

Comment: Ok I did it. What now?

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
ones = True
while n > 0:
  out = ["1"]*n if ones else ["0"]*n
  ones = not ones
  n -= 1
  print("".join(out))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
## Read input as specified in the question.
## Print output as specified in the question.
n=int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for k in range(1,n-i+2):
        if i %2!=0:
            print(1,end="")
        else:
            print(0,end="")
    print()
```